# Lombok and Spock: @RequiredArgsConstructor doesn't hide default no-args constructor for a field with a type of interface

Tags: java, spock, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

It seems that @RequiredArgsConstructor is not working in the code below 
 - but only in a test using Spock framework, and only for a field which is of type of interface `Dao`.
Strictly speaking - **the code is working** while it shouldn't work in my opinion, taking into account that similar test under JUnit5 doesn't compile at all.
Could someone explain is it a bug, or a feature ?

```
package brumba;
public interface Dao {
    Integer getValueFor(Integer value);
}
```

---

```
package brumba;

import com.sun.istack.internal.NotNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Brumba {

    @NotNull
    final private Dao dao;

//  If you uncomment the below 2 lines, then the test fails
//    @NotNull
//    final private String name;

    public Integer twice(Integer x){
        return x * 2;
    }

    public Integer twiceDao(Integer x){
        return dao.getValueFor(x);
    }
}
```

---

The below code works fine - but only in Spock (a similar test under JUnit5 doesn't compile).
 It seems that Spock test somehow sees a default no-args constructor (while JUnit test doesn't see this constructor)
But when the 2 commented lines above were uncommented, then the test failed with the below error:

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: brumba.Brumba()
```

---

```
package brumba

import spock.lang.Specification

class BrumbaTest extends Specification {

    def "twice should multiply argument by 2"() {
        given:
            def testedObject = new Brumba();

        expect:
            y == testedObject.twice( x )

        where:
            x | y
            0 | 0
            1 | 2
            2 | 4
            3 | 6
    }
}
```

---

And this JUnit test doesn't compile at all:

```
package brumba;

class BrumbaJUnit5Test {

    @org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
    void shouldTwice() {
        Brumba br = new Brumba();
    }
}
```

the error is:

```
Error:(7, 21) java: constructor Brumba in class brumba.Brumba cannot be applied to given types;
  required: brumba.Dao,java.lang.String
  found: no arguments
```

Here are the dependencies I am using for this project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2-groovy-2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.0-M1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i don't see `NoArgConstructor` in `public class Brumba`

Comment: @Deadpool you can't see that - java compiler atomatically creates default no-arg constructor unless there is another constructor definied. Lombok `@RequiredArgsConstructor` should generate `public Brumba(Dao dao)` constructor, so in that case the class should have not this default constructor at all (it should be private - hidden) - but Spock test somehow sees this constructor and is able to instatiate an object of this class using this constructor.

Comment: i got you but i don't have idea on spock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I can confirm that this happens for me, too. I never noticed before.

I had to debug through source code and look at decompiled files in order to understand at least a bit what is going on here. I can tell you a few things:

- This is **unrelated to Lombok.** It also happens to any Java class with a single-argument constructor taking an object type (i.e. not a primitive like `int`), e.g. `String` or your `Dao`.
- It is **unrelated to Spock** because it also happens outside of Spock.
- It seems to be **related to dynamic Groovy runtime features.**
- I would rather call it a subtle bug than a feature, but I am not sure.

**Java class:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow;

public class Brumba {
  public Brumba(String name) {}
}
```

**Groovy class:**

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

class BrumbaApp {
  static void main(String[] args) {
    new Brumba()
  }
}
```

**Decompiled Groovy class:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow;

import groovy.lang.GroovyObject;
import groovy.lang.MetaClass;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSite;

public class BrumbaApp implements GroovyObject {
  public BrumbaApp() {
    CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
    MetaClass var2 = this.$getStaticMetaClass();
    this.metaClass = var2;
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
    var1[0].callConstructor(Brumba.class);
  }
}
```

The Groovy runtime class `CallSite` is actually an interface, but there is [`AbstractCallSite`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/99c538334fd11b7a1edf689e7f0159b82c29ef83/src/main/java/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/AbstractCallSite.java) implementing it. If we look at this method

```java
public Object callConstructor(Object receiver) throws Throwable {
    return callConstructor(receiver, CallSiteArray.NOPARAM);
}
```

and this definition

```java
public final class CallSiteArray {
    // ...
    public static final Object [] NOPARAM = new Object[0];
    // ...
```

we understand that actually this method will be called

```java
public Object callConstructor(Object receiver, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
    return CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(this, receiver, args);
}
```

and so forth. I think what happens is that the `Object[]` of size 0 will be passed through as a constructor parameter somehow and the absence of an element interpreted as a `null` argument. This is also what you see in a debugger after object instantiation if like in your code the parameter is assigned to a member: The member will have the value `null`.